# elasticsearch GEO search order by distance from near to far

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-boot

a mapping `address` properties: `id` `name` `type` and `location`.
search mapping:

```
{
  "address": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "type": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "location": {
        "type": "geo_point"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

search cmd(filter `address.type = 1` and `distance = 100km`):

```
XGET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "type": 1
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "geo_distance": {
          "distance": "100km",
          "location": {
            "lat": 24.46667,
            "lon": 118.1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to search address match `type = 1` and geo `distance = 100km`; and I want to get the result that `order by distance ASC`. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are sorting based on distance, i moved match query inside boolean filter.

This should work

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                    "geo_distance": {
                        "distance": "1000000km",
                        "location": {
                            "lat": 24.46667,
                            "lon": 118.1
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "type": {
                            "value": 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "sort": {
        "_geo_distance": {
            "location": "24.46667,118.1",
            "order": "asc"
        }
    }
}
```